# How to use write.table when number of decimal places may exceed internal scipen option

Tags: r, write.table

Is it possible write the following vector without losing precision? The write.table documentation says that it has an internal equivalent of 'digits = 15' and it looks like scipen is being ignored.

```
a <- c(0.1111111111111123333, 0.11111111111111244, 0.1111111111111121111111)
options(scipen=22)
write.table(a, file="del.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format` function to control output before writing it to the table. For instance, the following code will format your vector output to 20 digits.

```
 write.table(format(a, digits=20), file="del.txt")
```

**Edit**: I've tried a few things, and can't seem to get R to not change the number. Here's what I've tried.

```
 print(c(0.1111111111111123333, 0.11111111111111244, 
         0.1111111111111121111111), digits=18)
```

[1] 0.111111111111112340 0.111111111111112437 0.111111111111112118

No good.

```
 a <- format(c(0.1111111111111123333, 0.11111111111111244, 
               0.1111111111111121111111), digits=19)
```

[1] "0.1111111111111123401" "0.1111111111111124372" "0.1111111111111121180"

No good.

```
 write.table(sprintf("%.100f", a), file='del.txt')
```

No good.

I'll keep looking for the answer, but hopefully somebody else will step in and clear it up.

Comment: if I run the two commands: a <- c(0.1111111111111123333, 0.11111111111111244, 0.1111111111111121111111)
write.table(format(a, digits=20), file="del.txt") i get a different output than the input: 
"x"
"1" "0.11111111111111234007"
"2" "0.11111111111111243721"
"3" "0.11111111111111211802"